# Create a regex that matches any word containing a digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to create a regex in JavaScript that matches every 'word' with numbers in it.

With word I mean every character sequence surrounded by whitespaces.

For example, in the phrase:

```
How much is: -2+3*5, sin(45), and 2+2?
```

It should do the three following matches:

- -2+3*5,
- sin(45),
- 2+2?

I've been trying to use word boundaries but I can't get it to work.

The best I've got until now was `/([-]\d.*\d)/`

Comment: Can you provide the regular expression you've been testing with?

Comment: Define "word" here please.

Comment: Hey guys, I've just updated my question with the things you asked for

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hs5e565a/)?

Comment: Whoa, thanks Josh, that seems good.
If anyone finds another way to do it using only regex it would be better, but for now this works like a charm.

Comment: @lucasfcosta does mine work for you (regex only)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\S*\d[^,?. ]*
```

This matches any non-space characters, a digit, and any character that is not `,`, `?`, or `.`.

Explanation:

[image: Regexper Image]

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3c9j7)

Comment: Whoa! That's awesome!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
(?=\S*\d)\S*
```

See [Regex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lK8eC7/4)